# Problem importing csv file into Pycharm with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

I'm trying to import a csv file into pycharm, but getting several errors. I have struggled a bit formatting the numbers in the file, so I wonder if that might cause problems.
I use:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("DAX_four_years.csv")
```

When opened in Wordpad the first few lines of the file looks as below:

```
Date;Open;High;Low;Close
02-09-2016 10:00;10556.00;10577.50;10549.00;10565.50
02-09-2016 11:00;10566.00;10572.50;10556.50;10567.50
02-09-2016 12:00;10568.00;10599.50;10543.00;10582.50
02-09-2016 13:00;10583.00;10662.00;10582.50;10638.00
02-09-2016 14:00;10638.50;10669.00;10621.00;10660.00
02-09-2016 15:00;10660.50;10699.00;10660.00;10693.50
02-09-2016 16:00;10692.50;10694.50;10668.50;10682.50
02-09-2016 17:00;10682.50;10689.50;10674.00;10680.00
```

It gives the following error:
[image]

Comment: Are you totally sure that the file is in the current directory and has exactly this name?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path of the file `DAX_four_years.csv`. In your case, you should place the csv file into the same directory of your python code. If it is located in a different directory, you should define the specific path.

For example, if the path of the file is `E:\DAX_four_years.csv`, you can use `pd.read_csv(r"E:\DAX_four_years.csv")`

Comment: TY very very much. Solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the csv file in the same directory as the python code file.

Comment: TY very very much. Solved the problem.